# SignalR exception kills the service/app - System.Threading.Tasks.TaskExceptionHolder.Finalize()

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, signalr.client, finalizer, aggregateexception

I've been battling this issue for sometimes. A windows service targeting .NET 4.0 creates a .NET signalr client but gets killed after sometimes for `System.Threading.Tasks.TaskExceptionHolder.Finalize()` due to aggregate exception thrown within the task.  Here is the gist of the setup - other details are omitted.

**Windows service:**

```
onStart()
{
   try {
         var task1 = new Task(SignalrEnv.WireUp(),TaskCreationOption.LongRunning);
         task1.Wait();
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
      //log the exception
   }
}
```

**SingalrEnv class:**

```
public void WireUp(){
   //create hubconnection
   //Create hubproxy

   try 
   {
         var task = Hubconnection.Start();
         task.Wait();
   }
   catch(AggregateException agex)
   {
       //observe the inner exceptions so the service won't crash
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
       //Log the exception
   }
}
```

However, when Signalr throws exceptions inside the signalr client framework like `OnError-System.TimeoutException` or any network exceptions, the windows service ends up getting killed.  I even tried handling the `Taskscheduler.UnObservedTaskException` but no avail. So it seems the exceptions are thrown in another thread and aren't handled there. With my setup, I should be capturing the exceptions and observing - preventing the crash. What am I missing in handling exceptions in TPL and signalr?

Note: On systems with .net 4.5, the service has no problem - no crash - since Microsoft made it a default behavior.  One would have to enable the crashing behavior explicitly in web.config.